# Best way to handle returns in predicate

Tags: kotlin

When I return a function in a predicate the compiler doesn't register it and still complains

> A 'return' expression is required for a function with a block body

The solution I found is putting a throw after the predicate.

```
fun boo(): Int {
    sth.apply {
        return sthElse
    }
    throw Exception("Unkown View type")
}
```

I wonder if there is a more gracious way.

p.s: The actual android code

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_category_node, parent, false)
            .apply {
                return CategoryNodeViewHolder(this, this@CategoriesAdapter)
    }
    throw Exception("View type error")
}
```

Comment: The code does not make much sense, why would you use apply here?

Comment: I added the actual code

Comment: That didnt help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'run' extension function should be used in these situations. Acording to [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) **run**

> Calls the specified function block and returns its result.

My code looks like this now

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
      return LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_category_node, parent, false)
            .run {
                 CategoryNodeViewHolder(this, this@CategoriesAdapter)
            }
    //throw Exception("Unkown View type")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: after seeing your example:

```
   override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int)
=  LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_category_node, parent, false)
            .let {
                CategoryNodeViewHolder(this, this@CategoriesAdapter)
            }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Its returning 'sth'. What kind of context would help?

Comment: now the (first) this argument is pointing to the whole class and not to the inflated view. Turns out the correct answer is 'run'. These extension functions need a little getting used to :)

Comment: I think you should not use run here - I think let is more correct - just replace this with it

Answer (score 0):

The apply function already has a return statement of the object it is being called upon, see https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int) =
   CategoryNodeViewHolder(
       LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).apply{
       inflate(R.layout.item_category_node, parent, false) 
       }, this@CategoriesAdapter)
```

This is now returning the correct object type for the method, while instantiating the layoutInflater as well as applying the inflation required for the CategoryNodeViewHolder before it is used to instantiate the CategoryNodeViewHolder.